# How to prevent password expiration in apache Archiva

Tags: security, archiva

I am running a standalone Archiva 2.2.0 installation. I added `security.properties` file to  ~\conf directory. In `security.properties` I defined:

```
security.policy.password.expiration.days=999999
security.policy.password.expiration.enabled=false
```

However, Archiva keeps complaining that the admin password has expired.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Archiva ignoring Security.properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790729/archiva-ignoring-security-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. In my case I stopped the admin password from expiring regularly by noticing that the properties had been copied into the main archiva.xml file.

Specifically, you need to change the `expiration` settings within the `configurationProperties` block.

```
<expiration>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <days>999999</days>
</expiration>
```

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822680/527160) for how to go about it.